# How to get routes from the specific app in pcf command?

Tags: cloud-foundry

the below commands provides all the information for that application. how to get the routes and store into variable.

cf app app-name

name:              Example
requested state:   started
routes:            route1,route2
stack:             cflinuxfs2
buildpacks:        Javabuildpack40

how to read and store into variable to use further in the jenkins job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cf app <app-name> | grep 'routes:' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | xargs`.

This will filter out all lines except the line displaying your routes, trim off the leading `routes:` (cut) and whitespace (xargs).

If you want it in a variable, run `MY_ROUTES=$(cf app <app-name> | grep 'routes:' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | xargs)`. This will result in a comma separated list of routes in the variable.

Ex: `route1.example.com, route2.example.com, route3.example.com`.

You could pick out a specific route by using `echo $MY_ROUTES | cut -d ',' -f <num>` where `<num>` is the number of the route you want (eg. 1 is route1.example.com, 2 is route2.example.com and 3 is route3.example.com).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Write a **Shell Script** to execute

> cf app APP_NAME

And then read the output. Writing a Wrapper script around CF-CLI commands is the wise way to deal this